# Display my activity and not the list itself Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-listview

I have problem, I want to display my activity segregate_waste_activity.xml in class SegregateWasteActivity.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:text="Search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="search"/>

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="A"/>

     </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp" />

     <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="800dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and I want to display data from classNames in my ListView with segregate_waste_activity.xml
If I want to invoke to segregate_waste_activity I get error.

```
 public class SegregateWasteActivity extends ListActivity {
         /*   protected EditText searchText;
            protected SQLiteDatabase db;
            protected Cursor cursor;
            protected ListAdapter adapter;*/
            String classNames[] = {"Test"};
            ListView myList;





     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classNames));
     }

     @Override
     protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
         super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
         String openClass = classNames[position];
         try{
             Class selected = Class.forName("com.odpad.odpadygdansk." + openClass);
             Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this, selected);
             startActivity(selectedIntent);
         }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list should have the following id

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

and call `setContentView()` in the `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show your activity's layout, then you need to call `setContentView(R.layout.segregate_waste_activity )` after `super.onCreate()`